# Will this React Component impact performance if used on hundreds of Table Cells?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks

Pretty new to React, and I was wondering if this component is being used on potentially hundreds of table cells (thus the `useEffect` hook executed for each) and could impact performance.

```
export const TruncatedTextWithTooltip = ({ children }: TruncatedTextWithTooltipProps) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [isTrucated, setIsTruncated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const input = inputRef.current;
    if (input !== null) {
      setIsTruncated(input.scrollWidth > input.clientWidth);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Tooltip label={children} isDisabled={!isTrucated}>
      <Text ref={inputRef} isTruncated>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes. Also you should be getting warnings, when you use this component multiple times, since you didn't specify any key. You may also want to memoize your props using react.memo

Comment: @Makusium, I'm not getting any warnings.  There's no key since it's not in a loop; just used to display a value in a table cell.   Do I want to remember props?  It's a different value that gets passed in for each component instance.  (Not that I learned useMemo yet)

Comment: Alright, when you're not using it in a loop or multiple locations, then there is no need to look after performance. Not usememo but React.Memo it's a different one - it only rerenders the component when the props have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I check full page load times (for the same page/data) repeatedly with and without using this custom component)

There have been no notable differences in the duration of the page loads.

So I guess the answer is "no, it's ok" but not sure why (yet..learning a bit every day)